# Expectation value : trials with and without replacement

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution

> Two cards are drawn at random from a deck of cards. Let X be the
>   number of aces obtained. Then the value of E(X) is

**Direct Method**
$$
P(X=0)=P(\text{no ace})=\frac{{}^{48}C_2}{{}^{52}C_2}=\frac{48*47}{52*51}\\
P(X=1)=P(1 \text{ ace and }1\text{ non-ace})=\frac{{}^{4}C_1.{}^{48}C_1}{{}^{52}C_2}=\frac{4*48*2}{52*51}\\
P(X=2)=P(2 \text{ non-ace})=\frac{{}^{48}C_2}{{}^{52}C_2}=\frac{4*3}{52*51}
$$
$$
E(X)=\frac{384+24}{52*51}=\frac{408}{2652}=\frac{2}{13}
$$
**Doubt**

In some references it is solved by considering it a Bernoulli trial, Pls check [Method](https://www.teachoo.com/4125/766/Ex-13.4--17---Let-X-be-number-of-aces.-Then-value-of-E(X)-is/category/Ex-13.4/).

If the experiment was with replacement, without doubt I'd say it a Bernoulli trial.

$$n=2\\p=\frac{4}{52}=\frac{1}{13}\\
E(X)=np=2*\frac{1}{13}=\frac{2}{13}$$

Why do we have the expectation value matching the one with replacement (Bernoulli trial) ?

Comment: What's the question?  This is a simple problem using Linearity, or you could just work out each case directly.  What are you asking?

Comment: If you are just confused about independence, note that Linearity holds even when the events are dependent.  Take an extreme case of dependence...suppose are only counting how many times the $A\spadesuit$ is drawn.  Since each draw is a win with probability $\frac 1{52}$ the expectation is $\frac 2{52}$ which is easily verified by direct calculation.

Comment: @lulu yea thats right. my doubt is whether it is a Bernoulli trial, ie. binomial distribution or not ?

Comment: Is what a Bernoulli trial? Each separate draw? Assuming you are drawing without replacement then, no.  It is impossible, say, to do $50$ trials without a win.  If, on the other hand, you are replacing after each trial, then yes.

Comment: Worth noting:  The expectation doesn't change whether you assume replacement or not.

Comment: @lulu When I assume without replacement, I get $E[X] = 1/2$ using the hypergeometric distribution. Did I miss something? More specifically:
$$1 \cdot \dfrac{\binom{13}{1}\binom{39}{1}}{\binom{52}{2}} + 2 \cdot \dfrac{\binom{13}{2}\binom{39}{0}}{\binom{52}{2}} = \dfrac{1}{2}$$

Comment: @Clarinetist The probability that a given card is an ace is $\frac 4{52}$.  By linearity, then, $E=\frac 8{52}$, replacement is irrelevant.

Comment: @lulu i have edited OP. Hope my doubt is better explains.

Comment: As I said, if you want to analyze the situation in detail you need to specify whether or not you are replacing cards.  This does not change the expectation, but it will change the explicit probabilities.  Also as I said, without replacement this is clearly not a binomial process.

Comment: I'll post the various explicit calculations below.

Comment: @lulu I understand your explanation; however, I would like to know why my hypergeometric calculation does not coincide with the $8/52$.

Comment: @Clarinetist  I don't understand your calculation.  You seem to be counting the number of spades drawn, of something like that.  (you did that calculation correctly!).

Comment: @lulu There are $\binom{52}{2}$ ways to grab a hand of two cards (hence the denominator). There are also $\binom{13}{1}\binom{39}{1}$ ways to grab a hand with one ace and one other type of card, and $\binom{13}{2}\binom{39}{0}$ to grab a hand with two aces, hence the numerators on the probabilities. Multiply them by $1$ and $2$ to get $E[X]$.

Comment: @Clarinetist  Not following.  There are $\binom 41\times \binom {48}1$ ways to choose Ace, non-Ace.  Like I say, your algebra works for "spades", of which there are $13$.

Comment: @lulu Oh wow, I mixed up the card values with the suits! HAHA! Thank you!

Comment: @Clarinetist  no problem.

Comment: OP: I'll let @lulu take this answer, but the short story is that since you're dealing with a non-replacement situation, $X$ follows a hypergeometric distribution.

Comment: Looking at the solution you linked, their first solution assumes the cards are replaced. Notice how for their distribution they have $P(X=2) = (4/52)^2$

Comment: @WaveX So the first solution is wrong if it is without replacement right ?. And why the expectation remains the same for both with and without case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there is some confusion in the comments, I'll post some computations.

First of all, to specify the process here you need to say whether or not you replace cards after each draw.  That has no effect on the expectation, but it will change the case by case probabilities.

In either case (with or without replacement) the probability that a single draw is an Ace is $\frac 4{52}$ hence, by Linearity of Expectation $$E=\frac 8{52}=0.153846154$$

With replacement:  Here we have a straight Binomial process.  The probability of drawing exactly $i$ Aces is $$P_i=\binom 2i\times \left(\frac 1{52}\right)^i\times \left(\frac {51}{52}\right)^{2-i}$$ whence

The case by case probabilities are $$P_0=0.852071006\quad P_1=0.142011834\quad P_2=
0.00591716$$ and we can then confirm the expectation.

Without replacement:  Now we get $$P_0=\frac {48}{52}\times \frac {47}{51}=0.850678733\quad P_1=2\times \frac 4{52}\times \frac {48}{51}=0.14479638\quad P_2=\frac 4{52}\times \frac {3}{51}=0.004524887$$ and, again, it is easy to verify the expectation.

Comment: Why the expectation value remains the same for both with and without replacement cases ?

Comment: I've given the detailed proof in each case.  Where is the confusion?   As an abstract matter, Linearity shows that we can compute $E[X_1]$ and $E[X_2]$ separately, without reference to the other (where $X_i$ is the indicator variable telling us whether the $i^{th}$ draw is an Ace).  In each case, with and without replacement, $E[X_i]=\frac 4{52}$.

Comment: I think i understand that for the case with replacement where, $E(X)=\sum_iE(X_i)=\sum_ip=np$ using the linearity of expectations. But, i am having trouble applying that for the case without replacement.

Comment: There is no difference at all in the application of the formula.  Using Linearity, we compute each term without reference to the other variables.

Comment: But in that case $E(X_i)$ are not the same right ?. $E(X_1)=0*\frac{48}{52}+1*\frac{4}{52}=\frac{4}{52}$, How do I find $E(X_2)$ ?

Comment: $X_2$ is the same as $X_1$ there is no difference between them.  I have written out very complete computations for both cases.  Please review the computations I have written out in my posted solution...you should be able to confirm that the expectations match, even though the individual probabilities do not.

Comment: ok. so what abt the linearity of variance? still holds ?

Comment: No, it does not.  Work it out in this example, for instance.

Comment: Alright. SO if $\chi:$# of success in the population, $N:$total # of elements, then $P(X_1\text{=}1)=\frac{\chi}{N}=p\implies E(X_1)=1*P(X_1=1)
+0*P(X_1=0)=P(X_1=1)=p$ and $P(x_2=1)=P(X_2=1|X_1=1)P(X_1=1)+P(X_2=1|X_1=0)P(X_1=0)=\frac{\chi-1}{N-1}.\frac{\chi}{N}+\frac{\chi}{N-1}.\frac{N-\chi}{N}=\frac{\chi^2-\chi+\chi N-\chi^2}{N(N-1)}=\frac{\chi}{N}=p\implies E(X_2)=1*P(X_1=1)
+0*P(X_1=0)=P(X_1=1)=p$. Thus, $E(X)=\sum_iE_i(X)=\sum_ip=np$.Right ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

"First card is an Ace" and "Second card is an Ace" are indeed Bernoulli events each with probability $\frac{4}{52}$, so the expected number of Aces as the first card is $\frac{4}{52}$ and the expected number of Aces as the second card is also $\frac{4}{52}$

They are not independent so you do not have a binomial distribution for the two cards together; you in fact have a hypergeometric distribution

But you do not need independence or a binomial distribution to find the expected number of Aces in the first and second cards. [Linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) is enough to give you $E[X]= \frac{4}{52}+\frac{4}{52} = \frac{2}{13}$

Comment: For the case with replacement, the formula $E(X)=np$ comes from the linearity property, as $E(X_i)=p$ for each trial, right ?. But, how do I apply it for the case with no replacement ?

Comment: @ss1729 - it is exactly the same: $E[X]=np$ applies without replacement too - in fact it is better in the sense that the variance of $X$ is smaller

Comment: In the case without replacement for each trial $p$ is different right ?

Comment: @ss1729 The marginal probability is the same $p=\frac4{52}$ here for each trial, but without replacement they are not independent

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/) is a great article on the topic of Linearity of Expectation. To understand your specific question in the case without replacement (and why the expectations are still the same for all 3 cases), let X be the random variable that denotes the number of aces drawn after 2 draws without replacement. We have:

$$ E(X) = E(A) + E(B) $$

where A is the random variable s.t. A = 1 when the 1st card is an ace, and 0 otherwise; B = 1 when the 2nd card is an ace, and 0 otherwise.

E(A) is a simple case:
$$ E(A) = \sum_A P(A) * A $$
$$ = 0 * P(A=0) + 1 * P(A=1) $$
$$ = P(A=1) $$
$$ = 4/52 $$

E(B) will be the same as E(A), even though A and B are not independent:
$$ E(B) = \sum_B P(B) * B $$
$$ = 0 * P(B=0) + 1 * P(B=1) $$
$$ = P(B=1) $$
$$ = P(B=1 \cap A=1) + P(B=1 \cap A=0) $$
$$ = P(B=1 | A=1) * P(A=1) + P(B=1 | A=0) * P(A=0) $$
$$ = \frac{3}{51} * \frac{4}{52} + \frac{4}{51} * \frac{48}{52} $$
$$ = \frac{4}{52} * (\frac{3}{51} * \frac{48}{51}) $$
$$ = \frac{4}{52} * 1 = \frac{4}{52} $$

You can read the article to see the proof of why Linearity of Expectation applies to dependent variables.